# Unable to set a cookie in Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions

I have a Azure function named "Login" in which I am authenticating users against my database. If its a valid user I want to set a cookie and send to browser. I am using the following code:

```
CookieOptions option = new CookieOptions();
                option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
                option.HttpOnly = true;

                req.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("KTAuth", User.UserId.ToString(), option);
```

The problem I am facing is that I am unable to read this cookie in JavaScript. I used the following code in JavaScript.

```
function getCookie(cname) {
var name = cname + "=";
var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
}
return "";
}
```

Any suggestions/ pointers here will help.

Comment: Hi, why did you unmark my answer ? If still have any problem about it, please let me know.

Comment: Yes. Its not working for me. I tried the approach you proposed but it did not work. Could it be becuase the web application and the azure service are working on different domains? I have enabled CORS.

Comment: Different domains may affect the cookie, you can have a try with `option.Domain = "xxxxx";`

Answer (score 2):

For this problem, you can't set `option.HttpOnly` with `true`. If we set `option.HttpOnly` with true, javascript can't read the cookie.

I set `option.HttpOnly` with `false` in my side and then I can get the cookie in my browser.

[image]